# where system_contract::claimrewards function is called

Tags: smart-contract, nodeos

Recently I've done some researches in term of how BP earning reward functions implemented. 
Eventually, I found out that is [system_contract::claimrewards](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/012dc0123f29b50695d27fba0ea4730e528e2c71/contracts/eosio.system/producer_pay.cpp#L68) however I can't find where it's called.
I searched whole project and could not find which function calls it. 
Could some one please help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This link may be helpful. Good luck!
https://steemit.com/blockchain/@eosiosg/system-contract-part-1-block-producer-rewards

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!